# iPhone pronouncing contact names with English accent

Tags: iphone, siri

Why is my iPhone pronouncing contact names with English accent? On my friends iPhone Siri is speaking in English but the caller name when I am recieving call it says in Czech language.

[image]

Comment: I'm a little unsure what you are saying here – is your iPhone pronouncing a Czech name in an English accent, although the name is Czech? What is your Siri language set to?

Comment: Siri can´t speak in Czech I have Siri set in english. But caller name it says in english accent. On my friends iPhone it says in Czech pronounce. Thats is weird, because I can’t find how to set it...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Is your friend's language set to English as well? And would you be able to tell what flavor of English (e.g. US, UK, Australia, etc.)?

Comment: Yes. We have the same settings. Of Siri and language settings too.